# How can i change my state in react

Tags: reactjs

When i am clicking the button, the state should be changed.how can i change my state.Initially clicked status false,whenever clicked the button the clicked should be true.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
class Static extends Component{
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   clicked_status:false
 }

render(){
   return(
       <div className="input-group mb-3 topA">
           <input className="input2" id="name" type="text" placeholder="  Name " /><br/>
           <input className="input2 mt-10" id="mail" type="text" placeholder="  Email "/><br/>
           <input className="input2 mt-10" id="passwrd" type="password" placeholder="  Password "/><br/>
           <span id="error_passwrd" className="text-danger fs12"></span>
           <input className="input2 mt-10" id="cpassword"  type="password" placeholder="  Confirm Password "/><br/>
           <span id="error_cpassword" className="text-danger fs12"></span>
           <a ><button type="submit" id="submit" className="button7 btn mt-10 bckgrnC" >Sign Up</button></a>
       </div>        
                   
   )
   }

 }
```

I am new in react,how can i change my state,what is process to change my state in react

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html from the docs. hope it helps

Comment: thankyou for referal @Paulquappe

Answer (score -1):

In react it is very easy to change the state.

1.You just write one function and bind that function

2.Write the onClick function to the button

3.Change the state through setState

Suppose in your example

```js
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.ChangeStatus= this.ChangeStatus.bind(this);
}
```

This is the function to write the change state. We can change the state through setState

> NOTE: Always use `setState()` method to modify the state of a component.

```
ChangeStatus: function(e) {
{
    this.setState({ clicked_status: true });
}
```

Add the onClick action to the button

```
<button onClick={this.ChangeStatus}>
```